# how to create an s3 bucket and objects with no public access in AWS using sdk go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

How to make this s3 bucket private so that all objects are also private by default ?

```
func CreateBucket(svc *s3.S3, bucketName string) error {
fmt.Printf("\n=====================================================\n")
fmt.Printf("\nCreating a new bucket named '" + bucketName + "'...\n\n")
_, err := svc.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    //ACL:    ACLPrivateRead,
})

if err != nil {
    if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        if awsErr.Code() == "409" {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return err
}

return nil
```

}

Comment: I am new to Golang coding. Could some one help me on this

Comment: This is a very poor question according to community guidelines. You should google this and try out few solutions. And then ask what is working and what's not. Just asking for ready to use solution with any efforts is not a way to go here.

Comment: @HussainMansoor I was able to create bucket but by default it creates the bucket with public access. My question was to create a bucket with private access

Comment: My code : 
func CreateBucket(svc *s3.S3, bucketName string) error {
 fmt.Printf("\n=====================================================\n")
 fmt.Printf("\nCreating a new bucket named '" + bucketName + "'...\n\n")
 _, err := svc.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
  Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
  //ACL:    ACLPrivateRead,
 })

 if err != nil {
  if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
   if awsErr.Code() == "409" {
    return nil
   }
  }

  return err
 }

 return nil
}

Answer (score 0):

From official Go SDK documentation, you can use `PublicAccessBlockRequest` to check if the bucket allows Public Access. This Block Request works in a way that it should be True / enabled to block public access. There are methods to Get, Put, Delete this config from bucket.

Reference to documentation with functions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CreateBucket